# Использование шаблонов для указания имен методов

Tags: c++, классы, шаблоны-с++, методы

Подскажите как более правильно и красиво реализовать следующую задумку:

Есть некоторый класс `CTasksManager`, у которого есть публичный метод `CTasksManager::start`, который подготавливает данные и запускает потоки, в каждом из которых используется приватный метод `methodN` (`method1`, `method2`, ..., `methodN`).

Иногда мне требуется, чтобы `start` работал с одним методом, иногда с другим. Но всегда с одним и тем же в процессе выполнения программы (т.е. не динамический выбор метода).

Заходить в нужный файл и править один вызов на другой - это некрасиво и вообще детский сад :), поэтому мне кажется, что лучшее решение - использование шаблонов, например так:

```
class CTasksManager
{
private:
    void method1();
    void method2();

public:
    void start();
};
```

Т.е. чтобы вызовы можно было бы делать так:

```
CTasksManager tasksManager;

tasksManager.start<CTasksManager::method1>();
...
tasksManager.start<CTasksManager::method2>();
```

Можно ли это реализовать силами стандартного C++ (без буста) и если да, то как?
Может есть более правильный способ?

Comment: Не ясно. Зачем вам вдруг понадобилось передавать сам метод именно *шаблонным* аргументом? При чем здесь шаблоны вообще?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для этого можно обойтись без шаблонов, передавая указатель на метод (причем метод должен стать публичным):

```
class CTasksManager
{
public:
    void method1();
    void method2();

    using t_PointerToMethod = void ( CTasksManager::* )(void);
    void start(t_PointerToMethod const p_method)
    {
         return (this->*p_method)();
    }
};

tasksManager.start(&CTasksManager::method1);
```

Comment: да, этот вариант я в голове держал, но мне кажется тут 2 недостатка
1) надо передавать именно как параметр 2) метод должен быть публичный, а хотелось бы сделать его приватным

Comment: @Zhihar 1) с шаблоном придется все равно передавать его, только как параметр шаблона 2) с шаблоном для вызова снаружи все равно придется делать методы публичными.

Comment: просто я сказал про шаблоны - потому что эта вещь используется на этапе компиляции, а не выполнения, поэтому и подумал, что можно будет обойтись без физических параметров, т.е. что будет использоваться уже на этапе выполнения :(

Comment: @Zhihar При использовании шаблона компилятор вам любезно накомпилирует отдельные функции на каждый вариант шаблона отличающиеся только вызываемым методом. А так у вас будет только одна функция  с одним параметром.

Comment: VTT, я это понимаю, что при шаблонах код масшабируется в зависимости от кол-ва шаблонов, но как раз с этим я готов мириться - т.е. увеличение размера исполнимого код меня устраивает, а вот разрастание или усложнение исходника не очень :) (программа - математические расчёты под себя, поэтому размером могу пожертвовать в угоду читаемости кода и скорости исполнения

Comment: @Zhihar Так при использовании шаблона у вас и исходник будет сложнее и длинее )

Comment: я думал, что я просто указываю как шаблон название (это главное - именно название) метода, который потом должен вызываться в нужной функции, а компилятор уже сам все скомпилирует и в итоге исходник будет компактным и самое главное - не важно какие методы - приватные и публичные. По идее я мог бы это сделать именно через шаблон, но тогда бы пришлось лепить новый класс, в котором были бы те самые методы, и через дружественный класс давать доступ к приватным методам, но это уже изврат редкостный

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно нечто похожее на [std::launch](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/launch). Посмотрите, как используется данное перечисление с [std::async](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async).